# DividendDistributor

Tags: solidity, tokenomics

where can I learn the implementation of this contract...I've seen many developers use this contract but I don't know where to find the documentation of this contract

Some of the code from the contract is

```
interface IDividendDistributor {
    function setDistributionCriteria(uint256 _minPeriod, uint256 _minDistribution) external;
    function setShare(address shareholder, uint256 amount) external;
    function deposit() external payable;
    function process(uint256 gas) external;
}

contract DividendDistributor is IDividendDistributor {
    using SafeMath for uint256;

    address _token;

    struct Share {
        uint256 amount;
        uint256 totalExcluded;
        uint256 totalRealised;
    }
```

Comment: https://github.com/indexed-finance/dividends

Comment: Hello thanks for replying but i think it is bot the same one as the one I have wrote above

Comment: What exactly is your question? Smart contracts don't have documentation. People write them as per their needs. What do you want from this code?

Comment: I want to completely understand how this code is written so I can also use it as other developers do

Comment: @Umar The contract you shared doesn't do much. They are functions and structs declarations without executable code.

Comment: yes it is not the full contract..the full contract can be easily found on github

Comment: Here is the full https://github.com/tintinweb/smart-contract-sanctuary-bsc/blob/74cf9ca766e80dc7fc2af7aee4ff6d896002b636/contracts/mainnet/1b/1b688e57c01d56da422a6bd533ab3d5a14610f78_Boge.sol#L12